# Missing GetTable<TEntity>() in database context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have `System.Data.Linq` in references, and also included as namespace, but my database context does not have `GetTable` method. It's just not there, no matter what I do.

It's an MVC5 project, on .NET 4.5.1, with Entity Framework 6.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Set<TEntity>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: Indeed I am. Looks like EF6 implements Set, instead of GetTable, which is for LINQ to SQL I guess?

Comment: Yes, indeed, GetTable is from DataContext when EF relies on ObjectContext

Answer (score 1):

*For others who may be looking for how to get the missing GetTable<TEntity>() method back for Linq to SQL:*

You must first add a reference to the `System.Data.Linq.dll` your project.

The GetTable<TEntity>() function is a Linq extenstion so you must actually import the Linq extensions by adding:

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your code file.

Comment: I just added this for additional info because it was a top result for the google search "datacontext.gettable missing"